# Select option selected an not selected

Tags: php, foreach, selected

I'm trying to Update a SQL Field so what i got is a Select and

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
....
$country_ausgabe = $row['country'];
```

So country_ausgabe as for example a value = de for german.

Also i have a array with all country codes in it.
So with this code i get all in a Select. $countries_de = the array with all country codes.

```
<select>
foreach ($countries_de as $key=>$country) {
echo "<option value='" . $key . "'>" . $country . "</option>";}
</select>
```

So but how can i use my $country_ausgabe to set this value in the select to selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this code

```
<select>
foreach ($countries_de as $key=>$country) {
$selected = ($country_ausgabe == $key)?"SELECTED":""; 
echo "<option value='" . $key . "' ".$selected." >" . $country . "</option>";}
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah but "stackoverflow" told me to wait 4 min more to accept :)

Comment: Done sorry, have to wait :) i accept every answer that helps me :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo "<select>";
foreach ($countries_de as $key=>$country) 
{
   $selected="";
   if($key==$country_ausgabe) 
   {
      $selected = "selected";
   }
   echo "<option value='" . $key . "' " . $selected . " >" . $country . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```